# Java process on a remote server terminates if PC that is connected to it via SSH shuts down

Tags: linux, ssh, java

I have a PC that is connected via ssh to an Amazon EC2 instance that has a running Java program. When I disconnect with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> everything is fine, the program keeps running as expected.

But if I turn off my pc or let's say the electricity is down (happens sometimes in my region) while I was still connected via SSH to that Amazon EC2 instance the Java program will stop running.

This is very annoying and I don’t have a clue how to solve this issue.
I run my program like:

```
java  -Xms2g -Xmx3g  -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -jar -Dlogging.config=logback.xml  -Dspring.profiles.active=prod web.war >> log.txt & echo $! > pid.txt
```

The server has an HTTPD process that sends requests to Java. If any other info needed please let me know, I will update the question.

Comment: Do you have to always run the service (java program) by hand, and do you have to watch its output directly?

Comment: Try running you hap usiung `nohup`: `nohup java  -Xms2g -Xmx3g  -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 ...`

Comment: @xenoid is this a solution for a reboot? The thing is that my server doesn't reboot, it just stops java process

Comment: @Fanatique how can I run it to prevent this issue?

Comment: When your PC reboots the connection drops and the java process parent disappears. in that case the Java process receives a SIGHUP and exits (this is the normal behavior on SIGHUP). `nohup` catches the SIGHUP and ignores it, so your Java process always has a parent (the `nohup` process) and keeps running.

Comment: Just to simplify what everyone is saying: When you disconnect from the Amazon EC2 instance, all processes connected to your user are stopped. This is normal behavior. What you want to do is to run the Java program as a background process or a daemon that will stay alive even if you log out. The simplest way is to use the `nohup` appended with a ampersand (`&`) method which other answers mention. Another is to setup Tomcat to run the Java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merely use nohup when starting your java process redirect output to a file and put it to background, in a bash shell:

```
$ nohup java -Xms2g -Xmx3g  -Djdk ... etc ... > myoutfile.log 2>&1 &
```

Once done, you can look at myoutfile.log to see if all is ok and logout won't stop the process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your java process stops because it bash process stops on ssh exit. And default behavior for bash is to sent HUP signal for all child processes (which basically stop your java process). here are example question on this topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294283/when-did-hup-stop-getting-sent-and-what-can-i-do-about-it
Proper way to prevent it  - create systemd or init.d startup service.

For AWS Linux 1  you will have to create init.d script. For AWS Linux 2 systemd used as service orchestrator .
Here are example scripts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503883/spring-boot-application-as-a-service/22121547#22121547

As workaround you may try to use screen or tmux - https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session/8657#8657

Answer (score 0):

If you launch the process as if it were an interactive program, through the shell, then it is completely normal that closing that shell will also kill all related processes. Even though you use `&`, the process still falls under the interactive shell's "job tracking" and will still receive a SIGHUP when the terminal is closed.

You can avoid this by using `disown` to untrack the background job, or by using `nohup` to make it ignore the SIGHUP signal.

However, that's not how services are usually started. The webservers everywhere don't have someone keeping an SSH connection open 24/7, and they don't have someone manually starting every Java app after a reboot – they use the *service manager* that the OS has.

For example, if systemd is available (i.e. if `systemctl` lists various services), then create a configuration file at `/etc/systemd/system/MyJavaWebapp.service` that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Website server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx3g -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -jar -Dlogging.config=logback.xml -Dspring.profiles.active=prod web.war
User=webapp
WorkingDirectory=/home/webapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With this you can just `systemctl start MyJavaWebapp` to have it running, as well as `systemctl enable` it to make the service manager automatically start it on every reboot. You can even include options like `Restart=on-failure` to make the manager automatically watch for crashes.

For Upstart or SysVinit (which are now rare), the configuration would be a bit different.